# Select count dependent rows from multiple tables with union

Tags: mysql, sql

In this case has three tables

4a and 4b is a main table

tbhari only a category table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `4a` (
  `kd_hari` char(5),
  `kd_ruang` char(1)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `4a` (`kd_hari`,`kd_ruang`) VALUES
('a_Mon','0'),
('a_Mon','3'),
('a_Mon','P'),
('a_Mon','0'),
('b_Tue','0'),
('b_Tue','0'),
('b_Tue','P'),
('b_Tue','4'),
('c_Wed','0'),
('c_Wed','P'),
('c_Wed','2'),
('c_Wed','L'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('d_Thu','3'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('e_Fri','0'),
('e_Fri','0'),
('e_Fri','0'),
('e_Fri','0');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `4b` (
  `kd_hari` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kd_ruang` char(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `4b` (`kd_hari`,`kd_ruang`) VALUES
('a_Mon','0'),
('a_Mon','4'),
('a_Mon','L'),
('a_Mon','0'),
('b_Tue','4'),
('b_Tue','0'),
('b_Tue','4'),
('b_Tue','0'),
('c_Wed','0'),
('c_Wed','3'),
('c_Wed','L'),
('c_Wed','0'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('d_Thu','0'),
('e_Fri','3'),
('e_Fri','L'),
('e_Fri','0'),
('e_Fri','0');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbhari` (
`kd_hari` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`hari` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tbhari` (`kd_hari`, `hari`) VALUES
('a_Mon', 'Senin'),
('b_Tue', 'Selasa'),
('c_Wed', 'Rabu'),
('d_Thu', 'Kamis'),
('e_Fri', 'Jumat');
```

i use this select query below.

```
select a.kd_hari,hari,
(select count(kd_hari) from 4a where kd_hari=a.kd_hari)jml
from 4a a,tbhari h where a.kd_hari=h.kd_hari and kd_ruang in('L','P')
union all
select b.kd_hari,hari,
(select count(kd_hari) from 4b where kd_hari=b.kd_hari)jml
from 4b b,tbhari h where b.kd_hari=h.kd_hari and kd_ruang in('L','P')
order by kd_hari;
```

above select query give me the result

```
+---------+--------+------+
| kd_hari | hari   | jml  |
+---------+--------+------+
| a_Mon   | Senin  |    4 |
| a_Mon   | Senin  |    4 |
| b_Tue   | Selasa |    4 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    4 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    4 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    4 |
| e_Fri   | Jumat  |    4 |
+---------+--------+------+
```

the problem is in above table result that jml column not count depends on kd_hari column data

then, i need the result like below.

```
+---------+--------+------+
| kd_hari | hari   | jml  |
+---------+--------+------+
| a_Mon   | Senin  |    2 |
| a_Mon   | Senin  |    2 |
| b_Tue   | Selasa |    1 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    3 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    3 |
| c_Wed   | Rabu   |    3 |
| e_Fri   | Jumat  |    1 |
+---------+--------+------+
```

look at jml column has count kd_hari or hari data with depends on kd_hari or hari column data.

Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: which one do you want to count?

Comment: kd_hari column and show count into jml column depend on kd_hari column data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overcomplicated your query, just use group by to get the counts by groups. Update: since you have the same keys in both 4a and 4b tables and you want to summarise them in one output, you need an overarching sum or count depending on the subquery you use

```
select kd_hari, hari, sum(rowcount) as rowcount from
    (select a.kd_hari,hari, count(a.kd_hari) as rowcount
    from 4a a,tbhari h where a.kd_hari=h.kd_hari and kd_ruang in('L','P')
    group by a.kd_hari,hari
    union all
    select b.kd_hari,hari, count(b.kd_hari) 
    from 4b a,tbhari h where a.kd_hari=h.kd_hari and kd_ruang in('L','P')
    group by a.kd_hari,hari) as t
group by kd_hari,hari
```

Alternatively, combine 4a and 4b with a union all in a subquery and join that on tbhari table and you can use count() with group by on the subquery that way because the subquery will include al rows from both tables.

However, the way I wrote the sample code you can take advantage of the existing indexes while joining the tables. If you combine them first with union and then do the join, then no indexes will be used for the join.

Comment: @GoetzPantana - just prefix it with a or h depending on if you want the 4a table or the tbhari table.

Comment: @GoetzPantana - No.  This is Shadow's answer.  Prefix it with an A or an H and if it works mark his answer as correct.

Comment: @GoetzPantana since you don't show us the sample data we have no way of knowing what is going wrong, this answer looks correct

Comment: Updated the answer to include the prefix. If you think it is still not correct, then kindly provide some meaningful feedback as to why this answer is not suitable to you and I can react to that. But writing that it does not work will result in my abandoning this topic.

Comment: @Shadow **That's Great**, I accept your answer. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: @Shadow part two topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079575/select-count-dependent-rows-from-multiple-tables-with-union-part-2